# MongoDB aggregation count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collections Users and Numbers. Each number has AllocatedToUserId (ObjectId) field, User can have many numbers. How can I in single query return User with NumbersCount? I wrote this

```
db.getCollection('Users').aggregate([
      {'$lookup': {from: "Numbers",
                   localField: "_id",
                   foreignField: "AllocatedToUserId",
                   as: "Numbers"}
      },{ '$project' : {_id:0,
                       document: '$$ROOT',
                       count: {$size:'$Numbers'}}}
      ])
```

But with this code I got structure of response like that:

`[{document, count},{document, count},{document, count}...]`

Where each `document` has `Numbers` collection, and I'd like to have `count` inside `document` and **without** collection of numbers. Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to project another field with the **`$$ROOT`** system variable, just project the fields from the users schema. The following example assumes you have a user with the schema:

**Exmple Users Schema**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId
    "firstName": String,
    "lastName": String,
    "age": Integer,
    "location": String
}
```

**Pipeline**

```
db.getCollection('Users').aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Numbers",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "AllocatedToUserId",
            "as": "Numbers"
        }
    },
    {   
        "$project": {
            "firstName": 1,
            "lastName": 1,
            "age": 1,
            "location": 1,
            "Numbers": 0,
            "count": { "$size": "$Numbers" } 
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, probably that's a solution, but my user schema has ~25 fields. That's why I used $$ROOT.

Comment: With `$$ROOT` you were still going to have another `$project` pipeline to flatten the `document` embedded document

Comment: So.. That's mean that's, probably, best solution?

Comment: Unless if it's a strict requirement to have a flattened schema as a result I'm afraid you may have to `$project` every field otherwise the `$$ROOT` is a better solution since you don't have to explicitly project the fields.